# Multiplatform runBlocking coroutine tests fail if last assertion doesn't have a Unit return type

Tags: kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm testing my coroutine functions in my Kotlin Multiplatform project.  I've mocked out the implementation behind them, so no actual await occurs during tests.

Consider the following test, curated from the test [README](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/README.md):

```
@Test fun testAsyncFunction() = runBlocking {
    val result: List<myClass> = myService.someSuspendFunction()

    assertEquals(result.first()?.name, "name")
    assertNotNull(result.first()?.someRequiredValue)
}
```

The second assertion has a return type of T, which causes its result to be returned to the `runBlocking` function, throwing the following error:

```
Invalid test class 'com.example.shared.core.service.ExampleTests':
  1. Method testAsyncFunction() should be void
```

I've found 2 solutions to this, either I can swap the two assertions around (`assertEquals` has a `Unit` return type, thus no issues), or write `val ignored = assertNotNull(result.first()?.someRequiredValue)`.  However neither of these two solutions are ideal, as I'll either have extraneous code that my IDE is warning me to remove, or my assertions are out of order.

What is the best solution to this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure where the multiplatform aspect comes in, especially given that `runBlocking` is not available in common code (only on JVM and Native). Note that you can use `kotlinx-coroutines-test`'s `runBlockingTest` for this kind of test instead of `runBlocking`. Its signature doesn't suffer from the same problem. Also as of `1.6.0-RC` the testing library has become multiplatform, so you can use `runTest` in common code

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the method is inferring the return type from `runBlocking`, which returns value from the inner suspending function.

You can force it to generate a `void` return type by specifying the return type `: Unit` explicitly rather than rely on the inferred value.